# grunt build not concatenating bower_components

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am using `yeoman webapp` to scaffold a basic application. I use `bower install --save` to install a couple of libraries which make their way into bower_components folder. Now I run `grunt build` and to my surprise the index.html file in the dist folder refers to the bower_components folder for the js files. I had expected the build process to automatically concatenate these files and put the concatenated script in the dist folder and make the index.html file refer to this concatenated file. What should I do to make this happen by default.

Comment: Hard to say from this. Show me the code :)

Comment: @Artjom - You want Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Any relevant code you think.

Answer (score 0):

Just facing the same issue on one of my project, a warning because of a bad file targeter was stopping the grunt build, and since the `usemin` task is the last to be run, my scripts was perfectly concatenated and minified, but the references in my html was not updated.

If you have like me an error, try to fix it or to run a `grunt build --force` to pass it.

If no, check that your scripts are correctly surrounded by the build tags

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/vendor.js -->
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And that you have correctly configure your `rev`, `useminPrepare` and `usemin` tasks

Little exemple :

```
rev: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            ]
        }
    }
},
useminPrepare: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
    options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
    }
},
usemin: {
    html: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html',,
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public']
    }
},
```

Also ensure that your `build` task is referencing to them :

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
   'clean:dist',
   'bower-install',
   'useminPrepare',
   'concurrent:dist',
   'autoprefixer',
   'concat',
   'ngmin',
   'copy:dist',
   'cdnify',
   'cssmin',
   'uglify',
   'rev',
   'usemin'
]);
```